# How to avoid including same file in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have a webpage that includes a Javascript file(`pqrs.js`) , I have a iframe in the same page that needs same js file , so `we need to include or download same file twice` . There is any way to avoid this .
Domain for Iframe and main page is same .
As fooo.com/xyz contains an iframe

foo.com/xyz

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://localhost/code/public/js/imageuploader.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe>
        <!doctype>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src='http://localhost/code/public/js/imageuploader.js'></script>
        </head>
       <body>
       </body>
        </html>
    <iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you don't need to worry about this second time it will get loaded from cache

Comment: No.If the domain both iframe and parent window is different, you should not do like this, beacause iframe does create it's own window and document from parent window. if you don't include that js in the iframe still it exist in parent window, iframe will not understand it.
It may possible if iframe and parent window have the same domain

Comment: Yup  , domain is different then it doesn't make sense , but in some situation it make sense as including library from CDN .